# Can't generate and use a value of some token within headers on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script using requests module to fetch some content from a webpage. My intention is to get 200 status code when I send a post http requests with appropriate parameters. So, this is the [site address](https://www.avis.com.au/en/home) and this is [the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG5my.jpg) that I filled in to generate the results. I just chose two options from the two dropdowns within the from and hit the `Select My vehicle` button to populate the results.

The way I've tried below works only when I hardcode `cookie` and `digital_token` within the headers. Please note that the `username` and the `password` are static.

As the value of `cookie` and `digital_token` are dynamic, it is necessary to produce them on the fly, otherwise if I hardcode their values, they expire in few minutes.

How can I generate and use the value of `digital_token` on the fly?

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.avis.com.au/en/home'
URL = 'https://www.avis.com.au/webapi/reservation/vehicles'

payload = {"rqHeader":{"brand":"","locale":"en_AU"},"nonUSShop":False,"pickInfo":"SYD","pickCountry":"AU","pickDate":"26/01/2021","pickTime":"9:00 AM","dropInfo":"SYD","dropDate":"27/01/2021","dropTime":"9:00 AM","couponNumber":"","couponInstances":"","couponRateCode":"","discountNumber":"","rateType":"","residency":"AU","age":25,"wizardNumber":"","lastName":"","userSelectedCurrency":"","selDiscountNum":"","promotionalCoupon":"","preferredCarClass":"","membershipId":"","noMembershipAvailable":False,"corporateBookingType":"","enableStrikethrough":"true","picLocTruckIndicator":False}

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': 'JSESSIONID=7-PfFQTdLoe4Allx772MXjNRHg-proLZhT7Wkn5k.w04vprecmapp02; akaalb_production_config=~op=avis_au:avis-au-us-wdc|~rv=36~m=avis-au-us-wdc:0|~os=7f956ca2417c5e686d715889b6a30f65~id=227f46458e1d74f397bc3732493d29f5; SessionPersistence=PROFILEDATA%3A%3DauthorizableId%253Danonymous; datacenter=cwdc; visitorId=cwdc-A6dcb0c81-876f-4200-b8b4-cf01d6665ad9; _gcl_au=1.1.1537375693.1611743635; _ga=GA1.3.666679016.1611743635; _gid=GA1.3.1276090703.1611743635; IR_gbd=avis.com.au; _fbp=fb.2.1611743635775.709997675; __qca=P0-236558422-1611743636477; APISID=f4bf5c40-9387-4319-b347-67a23e62ef8a; DIGITAL_TOKEN=86c21933-e3fe-4867-855e-256991d6c099-02-cwdc-ho4905; IR_8968=1611781534175%7C0%7C1611781534175%7C%7C; _uetsid=27fa7d10608b11eb994047dca2e1810a; _uetvid=27faeca0608b11eb8fe3e90805023a70; _gat_UA-6997633-40=1',
    'digital_token': 'eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..mPE_QHWlQV4uOqy6.3cB4yCaW_mvSRbigEXpvvB-Y_zxrixxddIdq0kzoNyQlJEGgsefnR-8cSHXxWgDWU6Tp5Wl6WFfOjfPETeh9gnFmQpokP2-vZ0pX6k288PAjqg7GbJoaiYo7fBsDAs3nQfu_lsRtvtoqh4ku5jptU8juVLYl7DuBzSs3KtmJobP6esWh8mrx0ezClpg1Qt0E4jpfmSYmCx0dbDgSyKYxp-fB3YD8DDBB1xrkCWFwCW4P4HQqtt6S1EYbW_FKsFmwI-wnyouSXfMXCCeEc8_Ib6PO1LBU3PaWfCGyzEW2M-Z8QeKLYXxp5GCmgQDRylm5JiVhIhWPDLh9TLcQGyWKABOR9wrM7FkUSUBh9fGX-O-HRc63AxDSZ5zn81Wo9roqPLt_BoAm-RYxbmSjxD298x8i10beEv8vu3IDjuqGmbldmEpvdST2gE_-KRKZAwKDcM8NCzU9LuG3Q3G6eSOJRL3jfMx37uqVpOSe9qMQEYBtMn_tUhKWmThsYLzvmH6bgvmCKaAwOgd2TzSI_kcieAidjOH-OJLEbJ9zrGNw6orGu6x7_UcC9r8fy5T8JbsNXrOFQE_LL3jkzNymlTXQRZOO51AOgoxuVrNJBM8TrzHftY7y5HVa_gQleLFG_uN_RGg3mr9fzKxjcGEHFt15RqqtY2V70LOEpQeKrPjC7B-D-UI0XHa3lOhBp3bIDz4tX-loFP3QOwn2e5Nmqk_O0pr9Lfzjbc0jnk-6iUIFsQzKl4G-eJwaUkN5n549BpeaFrpfwInNNloVdVTqDwGLYA-xcYnkNBozXFuNjkNwYjv66Zlwaj3_bC6sz-SySyu7rtwhdW85O8DREhj8I6xb-VvwDDGsb6-h0GgeCjGN7JZ4qkpZ4BvLyPu-YxeB6mz-xcO22-t9lyx8abABlm8oLdhOkYBDgA8x7exGzNMbUiDe_D61bsgnkTu6XIMKrm4HMOcT9ZsGcXkK2BZ909i_cXyTDpq26YLgTjEcH5Ob5NRC-eSAw4eeddDmeAxWlL4TixCESaKsbxC8sXRC7tURQDIasW6xLAAkVSTCnlkOV34luR3VOU6KaHvoa6RaAdKgFw5VXvCddFkhA_mqWhOO60Y1ow9wRWu65Z8M6VjqsU_rRvW8HMlfUqJ9I8EHQJ4yG3PcbNRxx4qzpXOs6TGsk9OMhQzPOaEoo4-hzaV4f54HeyZDFUx2gI8CEopbd1Shg1e0p1Mk0gEuM12550A--M6dvZ0oMLL4lv9XzEEe2mGy16gmiRsRkvEoFcumbM1XUuX3IkuCVHk9OcPNNlVPD2jIGT8prY8aHDP8aJ6wl0b1GtoiwDA6CAA9ePzRpLN4G617Wnotttmao5YVrcE_b1O0CQbfYqLQ_lPvTl1n4-P1p-YuiRwYAdw2BQEpOv0LyS1ekycEzWHN4-BOFr9MxQ.bZcUICoU7nJzaxeT0rENtg',
    'password': 'AVISCOM',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
    'username': 'AVISCOM'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    r = s.post(URL,json=payload)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: This form makes extensive use of XHR requests. I counted 19 in the first part of the process. These are requests triggered bt JavaScript. Requests has no JavaScript engine. To get the digital_token you will have to use something like Selenium. Is using Selenium an option for you?

Comment: Yeah, selenium might be an option only to produce the `digial_token` which I later may use within the headers while sending xhr. Please note that there is already a digital_token field available within cookies like `DIGITAL_TOKEN=86c21933-e3fe-4867-855e-256991d6c099-02-cwdc-ho4905;` which is useless. The working digital_token contains a huge value which you can see in the headers in my above implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned within the comments, this token is JS generated and can not be fetched using `requests` or `curl` or whatever.

An easy (but not very performant) way is Selenium using e.g. Firefox:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True   # Don't open a visible pop-up window
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.avis.com.au/en/home')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()

driver.quit()

print(cookies)
```

```
[{'name': 'akaalb_production_config', 'value': '~op=avis_au:avis-au-us-dal|~rv=37~m=avis-au-us-dal:0|~os=7f956ca2417c5e686d715889b6a30f65~id=a09a33378351c4e0fb1683926d7cf558', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False}, {'name': 'APISID', 'value': 'd3879ba0-bdec-488e-94f5-0c517b8d300f', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True}, {'name': 'DIGITAL_TOKEN', 'value': '89a7cd03-276c-4f2f-942f-07a5171a13d2-02-cdal-ho3904', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True}, {'name': 'datacenter', 'value': 'cdal', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True}, {'name': 'visitorId', 'value': 'cdal-A96653921-88e6-431a-9b08-2582dfe47a75', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1927796685}, {'name': 'SessionPersistence', 'value': 'PROFILEDATA%3A%3DauthorizableId%253Danonymous', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'www.avis.com.au', 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False}]
```

Here you already see your token. Fetch it e.g. via:

```py
print([ c for c in cookies if 'DIGITAL_TOKEN' in c.values() ][0]['value'])
```

```
89a7cd03-276c-4f2f-942f-07a5171a13d2-02-cdal-ho3904
```